# Youtube disable related videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm using Youtube iframe API to add a video to my page, but it's showing related videos when the video is about to end even though i have set the 'rel' parameter to 0.

Here is the concerned part of my code:

```js
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('homeplayer', {
        height: '1070',
        width: '1920',
        videoId: videoID,
        playerVars: {
                'controls': 0,
                'loop': 1,
                'modestbranding': 1,
                'rel': 0,
                'showinfo': 0,
                'playlist': videoID
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}
```

Maybe this question has already been asked but i can't find a solution as youtube api has been updated multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functionality of the `rel` parameter has changed; in August of 2018, YouTube deprecated it and in September of 2018 they modified the player API so you can no longer hide related videos. Rather, if you set `rel` to 0, the embedded player will only show related videos from the channel that the just-played video is from. If you omit `rel`, then the embedded player will show related videos from anywhere on YouTube. There is no longer any way to remove related videos altogether.

See https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018 for more details.