# How to disable related videos at the end of the youtube video in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, youtube

How to disable related videos at the end of the youtube video in react native..??

Below are my code, But its not working

```
  state = {
    isPlaying: true,
    related :false,
  };
```

```
<YouTube
apiKey="XXXXX"
videoId="XXXXX"
play={this.state.isPlaying}
rel={this.state.related}/>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently related videos cannot be disabled

You will continue to receive related videos from that YouTube channel

[google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018)

> The behavior for the rel parameter is changing on or after September 25, 2018. The effect of the change is that you will not be able to disable related videos. However, you will have the option of specifying that the related videos shown in the player should be from the same channel as the video that was just played.

[stackOver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53626655/9161478)